# Improve performance of ImageMagick thumbnail generation

Tags: php, imagemagick, thumbnails

I am currently generating thumbnails via ImageMagick's convert tool in this manner:

```
/usr/bin/convert input.jpg -size 140x93 -resize 740 -resize 186 \
-gravity center -crop 140x93+0+0 -format jpg -quality 90 jpg:output.jpg
```

But I feel like the conversion time is taking too long.  It's about 5 seconds per thumbnail on an 8-core 2.5GHz Xeon.  Is there any way I can optimize this or increase the performance while maintaining the crop and gravity center?

Thanks.

Comment: Why is this marked as off-topic? Questions about improving performance are off-topic? I would like to know how to increase the time that the `convert` command takes.

Comment: @SSH it's not related to programming.